# Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a option

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, typeerror

Here is my code:

```
let rec size = function 
    | [] -> 0
    | t::q -> 1 + size q

let rec n k v lst = match lst with 
    | [] -> None 
    | t::q when (v - size q) = k -> t
    | _::q -> n k v q

let () = print_int (n (3) (5) ([ 1 ; 2; 3; 4; 5 ]) )
```

It's saying the following:

```
File "main.ml", line 10, characters 33-34:
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a option
```

I don't understand what it means. 
I am trying to print the nth element of a list. I mean `print_int` is waiting for an `int` and `k`, `v` are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case of your function `n` returns `None` whose type is `'a option`.
You then proceed to return `t`, therefore the compiler deduce `t` must also be of type `'a option`.

You should use the constructor `Some` when returning `t`:

```
let rec n k v lst = match lst with 
  |[] -> None 
  |t::q when (v - size q) = k -> Some t
  |_::q -> n k v q
```

You won't however be able to use it with `print_int` right away, you will have to unpack the `option` type in the following way:

```
let () = match (n (3) (5) ([ 1 ; 2; 3; 4; 5 ]) ) with
  | Some v -> print_int v
  | None -> ()
```

Comment: This interesting. What Some actually do ? I don't understand what you mean by "unpack the option pack" ?

Comment: You are trying to write a function for which a set of input is non-sensical. Here, asking for a the nth element in a list that has less than n elements. The way to represent that in ocaml is to use the `option` type. It has 2 constructor `None` and `Some`. `None` represents the case where there are no correct value and `Some` the case where there is one.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the manual, or a book like "Real World OCaml". It is difficult to use a language if you don't know its syntax or semantics.

Comment: @Perry Yes the fact is just that I didn't know that None has this effect

Comment: It is not specific to `None` though, try reading up on how the types are handled in ocaml. There are larger implications than this specific case.

Comment: Can you provide a link on types where all of this is explained  ? Currently I am learning OCaml on their website the problem is that it's incomplete

Comment: As @Perry sugested Real World OCaml(https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/index.html) is a good resource. Try understanding the paragraph on type inference in Chapter 1 and then check out Chapter 7 for more on the `option` type.

Comment: Thank you ! I am going to look at this book.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `n` has type `int -> int -> 'a option list -> 'a option` because in the first case

```
 | [] -> None
```

you're returning `None` that is a value of type `'a option`, and on the second case

```
 |t::q when (v - size q) = k -> t
```

you're returning an element of the list. Since a function can have only one return type, the type inference algorithm unifies the type of the list elements with the option type, thus requiring the input list elements to have type `'a option`

The `print_int` function accepts values of type `int`, but you're passing something that is `'a option` that is not an int. Moreover, if you will remove `print_int` then the following expression won't type either:

```
let _ = n 3 5 [1;2;3;4;5]
```

because your `n` function accepts a list of options, not a list of integers, e.g.,

```
let _ = n 3 4 [Some 1; Some 2; None; None]
```

Comment: Thank you! And do you know if there is a way to actually print 'a option type ? Because print_int doesn't work here.